# how to register more than one UICollectionViewCell class in one controller in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

i am using two different uicollectionview with different two different uicollectionviewcell and structure of cell is also different how to i register both cell class in one controller view .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[HCTabBarItemCell class]
            forCellWithReuseIdentifier:[HCTabBarItemCell reuseIdentifier]];
```

In case if you load your custom UICollectionViewCell subclass from .xib file you should also register its nib:

```
    [self.collectionView registerNib:[HCTabBarItemCell nibName] 
          forCellWithReuseIdentifier:[HCTabBarItemCell reuseIdentifier]];
```

where class methods nibName & reuseIdentifier are declared and implemented in your (base) custom cell class:

```
+ (NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    return NSStringFromClass([self class]);
}

+ (UINib *)nibName {
    return [UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([self class]) bundle:nil];
}
```

Then just get your custom cell in cellForRow method by reuseIdentifier:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
                   cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    HCTabBarItemCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:[HCTabBarItemCell reuseIdentifier]
                                                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: i am using two different uicollectionview in one controller view with  two different uicollectionviewcell and structure of cell is also different how to i register both cell class in one controller view i am creating both class identifier nib and register but only one collection view work second one is not have any cell.

Comment: You register a nib with one identifier and then register class with another, try to have them identical identifiers using something like this: NSStringFromClass([TitleCollectionViewCel class])

Comment: In you cellForRow delegate method you should use reuse identifiers that was declared in registerClass: method.

Comment: can you give a complete code according my  code fille, i do this but it not work properly , only one collectionview initialize at a time. you see my code if it is possible give me complete code , it's very helpful for me. Thank you.

Comment: there is two collection view in Homeview.xib and it importing  two collectionviewcell class for each collection view, i want use both in one class(Homeview.xib),please give me complete code it helpful for me.